# My own theme's custom widget areas are not working

Tags: php, widgets, templates

I'm creating my first wordpress template and I want to add custom widget areas to my footer or my home.php file(tried both without any effects). I've already registered widget area in functions.php file and the only thing I get when I go to **Customize > Widgets** is:

[image]

The code i have is copy pasted from a tutorial website

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ? How can I add any widget area ?
Thank you for any tips in advance.

I tried registering them by putting code into function and calling:

`add_action('widgets_init','smth)`

but by using that style my wordpress doesn't show any additional widget area in **customize>widgets**

**FUNCTIONS.PHP CODE(widgets at the bottom):**

```
    <?php
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_theme_support('menus');

    /**
     * Enqueue scripts
     *
     * @param string $handle Script name
     * @param string $src Script url
     * @param array $deps (optional) Array of script names on which this script depends
     * @param string|bool $ver (optional) Script version (used for cache busting), set to null to disable
     * @param bool $in_footer (optional) Whether to enqueue the script before </head> or before </body>
     */
    function theme_styles() {
        wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css',get_template_directory_uri().'/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style( 'main_css', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('owl_carousel_css',
            get_template_directory_uri().'/owl_carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('owl_carousel_theme_css',
            get_template_directory_uri().'/owl_carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css');
        wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome',
            get_template_directory_uri().'/font-awesome47/css/font-awesome.min.css');

    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles' );
        /**
         * Enqueue scripts
         *
         * @param string $handle Script name
         * @param string $src Script url
         * @param array $deps (optional) Array of script names on which this script depends
         * @param string|bool $ver (optional) Script version (used for cache busting), set to null to disable
         * @param bool $in_footer (optional) Whether to enqueue the script before </head> or before </body>
         */
        function theme_js() {
            global $wp_scripts;
            wp_enqueue_script('jquery','https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
            wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, false);
            wp_enqueue_script('owl_carousel',
                get_template_directory_uri().'/owl_carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'),false,true);

        }

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js' );
        add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type' );
    function create_post_type(){
        register_post_type('slider',
            array(
                'labels'=>array(
                    'name'=>__('Slider'),
                    'signular_name'=>__('Slider')
                ),
                'public'=>true,
                'has_archive'=>false,
                'supports'=> array(
                    'title',
                    'editor',
                    'excerpt',
                    'thumbnail',
                    'custom-fields',
                    'revisions'
                )

            )
        );
    }

        function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
            $wp_customize->add_section( 'themeslug_logo_section' , array(
            'title'       => __( 'Logo', 'themeslug' ),
            'priority'   => 30,
            'description' => 'Upload a logo to replace the default site name and
            description in the header',
            ) );
            $wp_customize->add_setting( 'themeslug_logo' );
            $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo', array(
            'label'   => __( 'Logo', 'themeslug' ),
            'section' => 'themeslug_logo_section',
            'settings' => 'themeslug_logo',
            ) ) );
        }
    add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register' );

    add_action( 'customize_register', 'genesischild_register_theme_customizer' );
    /*
     * Register Our Customizer Stuff Here
     */
    function genesischild_register_theme_customizer( $wp_customize ) {
     // Create custom panel.
     $wp_customize->add_panel( 'text_blocks', array(
     'priority' => 500,
     'theme_supports' => '',
     'title' => __( 'Text Blocks', 'agrowinnica' ),
     'description' => __( 'Set editable text for certain content.', 'agrowinnica' ),
     ) );
     // Add Footer Text
     // Add section.
     $wp_customize->add_section( 'custom_footer_text' , array(
     'title' => __('Change Footer Text','agrowinnica'),
     'panel' => 'text_blocks',
     'priority' => 10
     ) );
     $wp_customize->add_section('big_text',array(
        'title'=>__('Duży tekst','agrowinnica'),
     ));
     // Add setting
     $wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_text_block', array(
     'default' => __( 'default text', 'agrowinnica' ),
     'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
     ) );
      $wp_customize->add_setting( 'big_text_block', array(
     'default' => __( 'default text', 'agrowinnica' ),
     'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
     ) );
     // Add control
     $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control(
     $wp_customize,
     'custom_footer_text',
     array(
     'label' => __( 'Footer Text', 'agrowinnica' ),
     'section' => 'custom_footer_text',
     'settings' => 'footer_text_block',
     'type' => 'text'
     )
     )
     );
     $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control(
        $wp_customize,
        'big_text',
        array(
            'label'=>__('Duży tekst','agrowinnica'),
            'section'=>'big_text',
            'settings'=>'big_text_block',
            'type' =>'text'
        )
        )
        );
      register_sidebar( array(
            'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 1',
            'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
            'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
            'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
            'after_widget' => '</aside>',
            'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
            'after_title' => '</h3>',
            ));
     // Sanitize text
     function sanitize_text( $text ) {
     return sanitize_text_field( $text );
     }


            register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'O nas',
            'id'   => 'o-nas',
            'description'   => 'O nas',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>'
            ));
             register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'O naso',
            'id'   => 'studio-text',
            'description'   => 'Studia',
            'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
            'after_widget' => '</div>',
            'before_title' => '<h2>',
            'after_title'   => '</h2>'
            ));

        function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
        'id'            => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );

}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init',0 );

}
```

**FOOTER.PHP**

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
<footer>
 <p class="footer-text">
 <?php echo get_theme_mod( 'footer_text_block'); ?>
<?php
if(is_active_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1')){
dynamic_sidebar('footer-sidebar-1');
}
?>
</p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you wrap the `register_sidebar` in a function and did a `add_action('widgets_init', 'wrap_register_sidebar_func');`?

Comment: When i do this that way my wordpress doesn't seem to find the widget area in functions.Now i have it normally outside of any function

Comment: what do you mean by `doesn't seem to see the widget area` the widget are doesnt show in the backend?

Comment: In functions.php i have teoretically registered 4 widget areas. One of them is registered as you commented before but as you can see from the screenshot my wordpress shows only 3

Comment: I am not talking about the customizer, if you go Appeareance->Widgets you see your widgets areas there? You need to use the `add_action` for a lot of reasons, if it's not working properly something it's happening with your theme

Comment: I don't have Widgets sub menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed your `functions.php` code:

```
<?php

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
add_theme_support('menus');

/**
 * Enqueue scripts
 *
 * @param string $handle Script name
 * @param string $src Script url
 * @param array $deps (optional) Array of script names on which this script depends
 * @param string|bool $ver (optional) Script version (used for cache busting), set to null to disable
 * @param bool $in_footer (optional) Whether to enqueue the script before </head> or before </body>
 */
function theme_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('main_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('owl_carousel_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl_carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('owl_carousel_theme_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl_carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('font-awesome', get_template_directory_uri() . '/font-awesome47/css/font-awesome.min.css');
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles');

/**
 * Enqueue scripts
 *
 * @param string $handle Script name
 * @param string $src Script url
 * @param array $deps (optional) Array of script names on which this script depends
 * @param string|bool $ver (optional) Script version (used for cache busting), set to null to disable
 * @param bool $in_footer (optional) Whether to enqueue the script before </head> or before </body>
 */
function theme_js() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('owl_carousel', get_template_directory_uri() . '/owl_carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js', array('jquery'), false, true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_js');

function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type('slider', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Slider'),
            'signular_name' => __('Slider')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => false,
        'supports' => array(
            'title',
            'editor',
            'excerpt',
            'thumbnail',
            'custom-fields',
            'revisions'
        )
            )
    );
}

add_action('init', 'create_post_type');

function mytheme_customize_register($wp_customize) {
    $wp_customize->add_section('themeslug_logo_section', array(
        'title' => __('Logo', 'themeslug'),
        'priority' => 30,
        'description' => 'Upload a logo to replace the default site name and
            description in the header',
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('themeslug_logo');
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Image_Control(
            $wp_customize, 'themeslug_logo', array(
        'label' => __('Logo', 'themeslug'),
        'section' => 'themeslug_logo_section',
        'settings' => 'themeslug_logo',
    )));
}

add_action('customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register');


/*
 * Register Our Customizer Stuff Here
 */

function genesischild_register_theme_customizer($wp_customize) {
    // Create custom panel.
    $wp_customize->add_panel('text_blocks', array(
        'priority' => 500,
        'theme_supports' => '',
        'title' => __('Text Blocks', 'agrowinnica'),
        'description' => __('Set editable text for certain content.', 'agrowinnica'),
    ));
    // Add Footer Text
    // Add section.
    $wp_customize->add_section('custom_footer_text', array(
        'title' => __('Change Footer Text', 'agrowinnica'),
        'panel' => 'text_blocks',
        'priority' => 10
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_section('big_text', array(
        'title' => __('DuÅ¼y tekst', 'agrowinnica'),
    ));
    // Add setting
    $wp_customize->add_setting('footer_text_block', array(
        'default' => __('default text', 'agrowinnica'),
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('big_text_block', array(
        'default' => __('default text', 'agrowinnica'),
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text'
    ));
    // Add control
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize, 'custom_footer_text', array(
        'label' => __('Footer Text', 'agrowinnica'),
        'section' => 'custom_footer_text',
        'settings' => 'footer_text_block',
        'type' => 'text'
            )
            )
    );
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control(
            $wp_customize, 'big_text', array(
        'label' => __('DuÅ¼y tekst', 'agrowinnica'),
        'section' => 'big_text',
        'settings' => 'big_text_block',
        'type' => 'text'
            )
            )
    );

    // Sanitize text
    function sanitize_text($text) {
        return sanitize_text_field($text);
    }
}

add_action('customize_register', 'genesischild_register_theme_customizer');

function wpb_widgets_init() {

    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Custom Header Widget Area',
        'id' => 'custom-header-widget',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="chw-widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="chw-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'Footer Sidebar 1',
        'id' => 'footer-sidebar-1',
        'description' => 'Appears in the footer area',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</aside>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'O nas',
        'id' => 'o-nas',
        'description' => 'O nas',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name' => 'O naso',
        'id' => 'studio-text',
        'description' => 'Studia',
        'before_widget' => '<div id="one" class="two">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h2>',
        'after_title' => '</h2>'
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init', 0);
```

your `wpb_widgets_init` function for the widget areas was inside `genesischild_register_theme_customizer` also there was one area outside.

Comment: Thank you so much for help ! The code moreover, now  looks really nice and clean.